# How can I make yeast- and gluten-free pizza dough?

Tags: substitutions, dough

I'm trying to make a yeast-free, no-gluten pizza dough for a friend who basically can eat neither, but loves pizza. The last try included water, rice flour, olive oil, salt, baking powder and guar gum, and although it was better than previous attempts (the dough held together after baking, and didn't turn into a giant crispy cracker) it was still not chewy and crisp as a traditional pizza would be. I'm not expecting a result that perfectly mimics traditional recipes (where gluten and yeast are involved), but would like to know if anyone has tried other flours and yeast replacements that can create a stretchier dough that will result in a crispy yet chewy dough?

Comment: Are you trying for mimicry of yeast-based pizza, or do you just want to recreate the essentials of the pizza?  If you just want something 'pizza-like', use a gluten-free biscuit recipe for the crust.

Comment: I've edited your title to specify your restrictions up-front. (For your original title, the answer is that obviously the only thing that can substitute for yeast is leavening, but that's not your whole question.)

Comment: Joe, I have edited the question to be clearer, I hope. I'm not looking for a biscuit pizza, or an English-muffin pizza, or a pita-bread pizza - I'm really hoping for as close to the real deal, minus the yeast and gluten.

Comment: If you google "gluten free pizza dough", you will find countless recipes.  here is one from a credible source:  http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/gluten-free-pizza-crust-recipe  Is there a particular technique question you would like to ask?  Or perhaps you are asking about how a particular ingredient affects the recipe?  Plain recipe requests are off topic at this site.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I think it's more a question of what to substitute for gluten and yeast to achieve a traditional pizzalike consistency. Most gluten-free recipes, including the one you linked to, still contain yeast, which the OP can't use.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read that particular recipe in much detail, just saw that it was gluten free from one of my "go to" sites...  didn't catch they were using yeast.  Thanks.  Its still a recipe request with the constraint of gluten free AND no yeast.

Comment: This one http://www.food.com/recipe/yeast-free-pizza-crust-gluten-free-298216 (no comment on quality) purports to be both gluten and yeast free.  Another:  http://www.celiac.com/articles/744/1/Yeast-free-Pizza-Crust-Gluten-Free/Page1.html  I found these by googling "gluten free pizza dough recipe no yeast" although you get some false hits on just no yeast that do contain wheat flour.   They can be found.

Comment: Thanks all. I am not looking for recipes as I realize I can google those, and have. Rather, I was hoping for input from users here who have tried to make a pizza dough without yeast and gluten along with suggestions and feedback on the taste, texture, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried making pizza crust w Garbanzo bean flour ([Besan or Gram flour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_flour)) with *some* success.
Starting w a recipe similar to this: [Chick Pea Tortillas](http://seemichellecook.com/2011/05/18/chick-pea-tortillas/). Leave the fried onions in, and add some olive oil. Fry until nicely browned, and use as crust for pizza. First time I tried, I left the batter too thick, and pizza was overly bready, almost pancakish. Up'd the water on second try and result was crispier, but too flimsy. Perhaps an egg. and some spicing? Haven't tried adding baking powder to the thin batter, but it seems there might be a workable recipe in there somewhere.

Comment: Your answer made me think of [dosa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosa) ... I've never made 'em, but it's a fermented rice & lentil batter, which can be cooked up crispy.  I just don't know if the ferment violates the 'no yeast' rule.

Answer (score 0):

Yeast definitely adds a lot of the classic "pizza dough" flavor, so you'll be missing that. However, you can still get some rise in the dough using baking powder, salt, and oil (2 teaspoons baking powder, 1 teaspoon salt, and 1/4 cup oil to roughly 2 cups of "flour" in your recipe). It sounds like you already tried that route, though.

But you also need the gluten free part, which is tricky. Have you tried a cornstarch and rice flour recipe yet?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I like...http://www.celiac.com/articles/744/1/Yeast-free-Pizza-Crust-Gluten-Free/Page1.html.  Sounds weird, but it tastes good.

Here's another...http://www.food.com/recipe/quick-bread-gluten-free-pizza-crust-280734. Hope this helps!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found that an equal amount of baking soda and lemon juice create a yeast like affect in dough, but you don't have to let it sit.

For example, I was making some gluten free yeast free bread a couple of days ago, and the recipe I was following called for 1 tablespoon of yeast,(or a packet). I subbed 1tbs lemon juice and 1tbs baking soda, and it turned out beautifully. I don't really eat pizza, so I can't help in that respect, but it might be worth a try!(: