# How should we determine the proportion of yeast in thin pizza?

Tags: pizza, yeast

It's my first try at making pizza. I have a question that I'm curious about and I can't find an answer for.

I would like to make a pizza that is thin, crispy, and a little soft. In my research, most of the recipes used yeast. I know that yeast adds flavor to the dough and that's why I want to use it.

I do not know anything about the ratio of yeast to other ingredients.  I am using instant dry yeast. How can I calculate the correct ratio for AP flour? In my first try, I put one packet (30 gr) instant dry yeast for 5 cups of AP flour. I have no idea if it is correct or not. The result was not so good. I want to make a good thin and a little soft pizza for my daughter and wife and I am searching for a good recipe.

I also can't find answers to the following questions related to thin, soft pizza of this type:

1. I will stretch the dough thinly. The yeast I use will make this dough rise. But I want a thin pizza. Isn't that contradictory?
2. It is said that I need to use fat for the pizza to be slightly soft, but the use of fat also weakens the gluten network. Doesn't the weakening of the gluten network prevent me from making thin dough? Every recipe says that gluten network should be strong.
3. In some recipes, they use a fork before baking the dough. Is the purpose to reduce the effect of yeast?  Can't I make a thin pizza without a fork?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  There are a few things you need to know from How To Ask https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/asking.  (1) Please avoid asking multiple questions at once.  Ask a single question, get an answer to that, and move on to your next question.  (2) Please search SA for related questions and answers; if you search on "pizza dough" you will find that there are already dozens of answered questions related to what you've asked above. (3) When referring to "recipes", please provide a link or transcription of the recipe so we know what you're asking about.

Comment: If you can break up the above into individual questions that have not already been answered on SA, I'll be happy to take a stab at it; I make a lot of pizza. Also, for th yeast quantities, you might want to check out the pizza app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fisico.pizzapp&hl=en_US

Comment: As @FuzzyChef said, there are related questions on this site.  See [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/35787/15018) and [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75534/15018) addressing questions #1 and #3.  Surprisingly, I can't seem to find a similar question to #2, at least not in a quick search (specifically for pizza).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the title of the question is about the "proportion of yeast" in pizza dough.  As the question doesn't elaborate further on that point, I'm not certain what that question might be.  Yeast proportions in pizza dough are typically similar to other breads, though sometimes a bit less, as pizza doesn't need to rise high.

As to the specific questions:

1. Yeast is used to improve the texture.  You can make pizza without yeast (or other leavening, like baking powder), but the result will have a flatbread texture that might be more cracker-like or doughy (depending on thickness and how long it is baked).  Traditional Italian-style pizza generally at least has a risen edge that is thicker.  And even thin-crust pizza is often improved in the center by having small bubbles that give a more leavened "bread-like" texture.  Also, yeast provides flavor during fermentation, so that's another reason it's typically added.
2. Yes, added fat will reduce the strength of the gluten network somewhat, which is one reason why many recipes don't add any fat to pizza dough.  However, a small addition of fat (generally olive oil) does produce a softer crust.  Using a high-protein flour (like bread flour or high-gluten flour), as well as making sure to develop the gluten well by kneading, folding, and shaping, will ensure that it's plenty strong enough for stretching.  In fact, a little added oil can actually help to make the dough easier to stretch into a thin pizza shape in its process of softening the dough.  My standard pizza dough recipe has some olive oil, and it stretches very easily until it's so thin you can almost see through it, but it rarely tears unless I'm not careful.
3. I don't really see the need to stab the dough randomly with a fork (though I have seen recipes that recommend that).  But some people use a fork or other utensil to pop any large bubbles in the dough before topping and baking.  It is useful to get rid of large bubbles, as they can grow significantly, and then burn or pop and cause toppings to get distributed unevenly.  This step isn't strictly necessary (depending on your recipe and how long you let the dough rise before making your pizza), and I usually only bother getting rid of particularly large bubbles.

Comment: Thanks again so much. If we stab the dough with fork, does not it prevent to rise dough while baking ? So it will be a pizza like a cracker that I do not want. Is large bubble is a different thing ?

Comment: @mhendek: Yes, when I say "large bubbles" I mean *giant* bubbles that are visibly sticking up out of the dough once you stretch it out.  I don't see the need to use a fork on smaller bubbles, as they help the dough to be just a little springy/spongy like bread.

Comment: You said "Yeast proportions are similar to other breads". I do not know anything about this ratio. I am using instant dry east. How can I calculate the correct ratio for AP flour ? In my first dry, I put one packet (30 gr) instant dry east for 5 cup of AP flour. I have no idea if it is correct or not. The result was not so good. I want to make a good thin and a little soft  pizza for my daughter and wife and I am searching for a good recipe. My questions are too basic I know. I will be so  happy if you can help.

Comment: @mhendek: I suggest that you might consider posting the recipe you used (either here or in a separate question) so that someone here can help you troubleshoot it.  It's almost impossible to answer these questions so broadly in a way that will help you have success, as so much depends on the particular kind of recipe you're using.  I don't know why your pizza attempt failed.  Why was it "not so good"?  Again, these are details to put in a question.  The amount of yeast to use depends on the proportions of the recipe, the fermentation time, and other things, so I can't answer it in general.

Comment: @mhendek: And by the way, it's not that your questions are "too basic."  They are good questions.  They just need to be specific in order for us to help you answer them.  And, as FuzzyChef noted in comments, it's better to break them up into separate questions unless they are all clearly related.